# What's the difference between "Frais de gestion annuels (max.)" (~expense ratio) and "Total des frais sur encours" (~expenses on outstanding amounts)?

Tags: etf, terminology, fees, france

I see two fees on the ETF report below:

1. Frais de gestion annuels (max.), which can be translated as expense ratio.
2. Total des frais sur encours, which can be [translated](https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/Total%20des%20frais%20sur%20encours) as total expenses on outstanding amounts.

What's the difference between these two fees?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Frais de gestions* corresponds better to "**Management** Expense [Ratio]" (MER) and *total des frais* to "Total Expense [Ratio]" (TER). The TER includes management fees plus various other expenses (trading costs, custodian fees, fund document fees, etc.)